# Fail to boot: mounting `/boot/efi` raises "IO charset iso8859-1 not found"

Tags: ubuntu, grub2, grub

I was using Ubuntu 19.04 for some time and wanted to try the recently released Pop!_OS 19.10. I want to keep using GRUB, but Pop!_OS (or maybe I did it while trying to repair) mangled my bootloader, so **I reinstalled GRUB** - but now I can't boot into my old Ubuntu 19.04 installation anymore. `/dev/sda1` cannot be mounted to `/boot/efi` - raising the error **"IO charset iso8859-1 not found"**. Soon after that message occurs the boot process stops and drops me to a shell.

[image: Photo of the error]

I've searched the last two days for a solution and tried wiping and reinstalling grub multiple times, but nothing has helped me so far.

**My goal** is to have GRUB set up, such that I boot into Ubuntu or Pop!_OS (depending on the menuentry I choose).

Here's the error I get:

```
root@my-laptop: mount /dev/sda1 /boot/efi
mount: /mnt/efi: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
[  473.093254] FAT-fs (sda1): IO charset iso8859-1 not found
```

`dmesg | tail -n 150`:

```
[    2.353284] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bios: version 86.04.8a.00.88
[    2.353451] ata2.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
[    2.354534] ata2.00: ATA-11: Samsung SSD 860 EVO M.2 2TB, RVT21B6Q, max UDMA/133
[    2.354537] ata2.00: 3907029168 sectors, multi 1: LBA48 NCQ (depth 32), AA
[    2.354548] ACPI: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[    2.355366] acpi device:0f: registered as cooling_device12
[    2.355456] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input7
[    2.355500] ACPI: Video Device [PEGP] (multi-head: no  rom: yes  post: no)
[    2.355533] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:13/LNXVIDEO:01/input/input8
[    2.357427] ata2.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[    2.357429] ata2.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[    2.357431] ata2.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[    2.357809] ata2.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
[    2.361467] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    2.361648] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      Samsung SSD 860  1B6Q PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    2.361812] ata2.00: Enabling discard_zeroes_data
[    2.361843] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[    2.361998] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.82 TiB)
[    2.362008] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    2.362010] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    2.362021] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    2.362095] ata2.00: Enabling discard_zeroes_data
[    2.364616]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3
[    2.364782] ata2.00: Enabling discard_zeroes_data
[    2.365831] fbcon: inteldrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    2.365925] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] supports TCG Opal
[    2.365926] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    2.394740] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fb: 8192 MiB GDDR5
[    2.437942] vga_switcheroo: enabled
[    2.438013] [TTM] Zone  kernel: Available graphics memory: 8129246 kiB
[    2.438013] [TTM] Zone   dma32: Available graphics memory: 2097152 kiB
[    2.438013] [TTM] Initializing pool allocator
[    2.438015] [TTM] Initializing DMA pool allocator
[    2.438021] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: VRAM: 8192 MiB
[    2.438021] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: GART: 536870912 MiB
[    2.438023] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: BIT table 'A' not found
[    2.438023] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: BIT table 'L' not found
[    2.438024] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: TMDS table version 2.0
[    2.438024] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB version 4.1
[    2.438025] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 00: 02000f62 00020010
[    2.438026] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 01: 04011f86 04600010
[    2.438027] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB outp 02: 04011f82 00020010
[    2.438027] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB conn 00: 00010061
[    2.438028] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB conn 01: 01000146
[    2.461395] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    2.461395] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[    2.462649] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: MM: using COPY for buffer copies
[    2.525842] [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes
[    2.527699] [drm] Initialized nouveau 1.3.1 20120801 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 1
[    2.589858] [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes
[    2.653842] [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes
[    2.726531] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried max coordinates: x [..5666], y [..4688]
[    2.757308] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried min coordinates: x [1274..], y [1166..]
[    2.757312] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Your touchpad (PNP: SYN150d SYN1500 SYN0002 PNP0f13) says it can support a different bus. If i2c-hid and hid-rmi are not used, you might want to try setting psmouse.synaptics_intertouch to 1 and report this to linux-input@vger.kernel.org.
[    2.818164] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 8.16, id: 0x1e2b1, caps: 0xf00123/0x840300/0x12e800/0x400000, board id: 3414, fw id: 2667658
[    2.856833] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input6
[    2.974104] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    2.994817] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=0539, bcdDevice= 2.06
[    2.994818] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=10, Product=11, SerialNumber=3
[    2.994819] usb 2-2: Product: External USB 3.0
[    2.994819] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Intenso
[    2.994820] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 20120712252C0
[    2.998739] usb-storage 2-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[    2.998941] usb-storage 2-2:1.0: Quirks match for vid 152d pid 0539: 4000000
[    2.998998] scsi host2: usb-storage 2-2:1.0
[    2.999042] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    3.000000] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[    3.121995] usb 1-7: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    3.271983] usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=1038, idProduct=1122, bcdDevice= 2.29
[    3.271984] usb 1-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    3.271984] usb 1-7: Product: SteelSeries KLC
[    3.271985] usb 1-7: Manufacturer: SteelSeries
[    3.401966] usb 1-14: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    3.465006] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x67
[    3.480361] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
[    3.551843] usb 1-14: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0aaa, bcdDevice= 0.02
[    3.552472] usb 1-14: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    3.700585] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    3.703220] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    3.703908] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    3.705609] hid-generic 0003:1038:1122.0001: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [SteelSeries SteelSeries KLC] on usb-0000:00:14.0-7/input0
[    3.706474] input: SteelSeries SteelSeries KLC as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.1/0003:1038:1122.0002/input/input9
[    3.766197] hid-generic 0003:1038:1122.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [SteelSeries SteelSeries KLC] on usb-0000:00:14.0-7/input1
[    4.010431] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Intenso  External USB 3.0 0206 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[    4.010680] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[    4.011034] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953523712 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[    4.011235] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[    4.011236] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 27 00 00 00
[    4.011482] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[    4.011482] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[    4.302455]  sdb: sdb1
[    4.303973] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[    8.565481] mce: CPU0: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[    8.565482] mce: CPU6: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[    8.565483] mce: CPU5: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[    8.565484] mce: CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[    8.565485] mce: CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[    8.565486] mce: CPU11: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[    8.565486] mce: CPU9: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[    8.565509] mce: CPU7: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[    8.565510] mce: CPU6: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[    8.565514] mce: CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[    8.565514] mce: CPU8: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[    8.565515] mce: CPU10: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[    8.565516] mce: CPU4: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[    8.566541] mce: CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[    8.577445] mce: CPU0: Core temperature/speed normal
[    8.577446] mce: CPU6: Core temperature/speed normal
[    8.577496] mce: CPU7: Package temperature/speed normal
[    8.577497] mce: CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
[    8.577497] mce: CPU8: Package temperature/speed normal
[    8.577498] mce: CPU10: Package temperature/speed normal
[    8.577499] mce: CPU4: Package temperature/speed normal
[    8.577500] mce: CPU11: Package temperature/speed normal
[    8.577500] mce: CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
[    8.577501] mce: CPU3: Package temperature/speed normal
[    8.577501] mce: CPU5: Package temperature/speed normal
[    8.577502] mce: CPU9: Package temperature/speed normal
[    8.578480] mce: CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
[    8.579382] mce: CPU6: Package temperature/speed normal
[    9.722964] NET: Registered protocol family 38
[    9.800418] device-mapper: crypt: xts(aes) using implementation "xts-aes-aesni"
[    9.906440] EXT4-fs (dm-2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   10.030518] systemd[1]: Failed to find module 'autofs4'
[   10.097955] systemd[1]: systemd 240 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 +IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid)
[   10.118053] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
[   10.125292] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <my-laptop>.
[   10.196986] systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/teamviewerd.service:8: PIDFile= references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/teamviewerd.pid → /run/teamviewerd.pid; please update the unit file accordingly.
[   10.217354] systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/anydesk.service:8: PIDFile= references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/anydesk.pid → /run/anydesk.pid; please update the unit file accordingly.
[   10.233042] systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/spice-vdagentd.service:8: PIDFile= references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/spice-vdagentd/spice-vdagentd.pid → /run/spice-vdagentd/spice-vdagentd.pid; please update the unit file accordingly.
[   10.236510] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
[   10.238535] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
[   10.240439] systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems.
[   10.242323] systemd[1]: Starting of Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point not supported.
[   10.263104] EXT4-fs (dm-2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   10.576763] systemd-journald[734]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[   10.684897] Adding 20971516k swap on /dev/mapper/luks-swap.  Priority:-2 extents:1 across:20971516k SSFS
[   10.964560] EXT4-fs (sda2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   10.973934] EXT4-fs (dm-3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   10.980548] FAT-fs (sda1): IO charset iso8859-1 not found
[   11.042392] audit: type=1400 audit(1572097473.688:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-xpdfimport" pid=1180 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   11.043052] audit: type=1400 audit(1572097473.688:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe" pid=1176 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   11.043054] audit: type=1400 audit(1572097473.688:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe//kmod" pid=1176 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   11.043162] audit: type=1400 audit(1572097473.688:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/ippusbxd" pid=1178 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   11.043414] audit: type=1400 audit(1572097473.688:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-senddoc" pid=1184 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   11.043533] audit: type=1400 audit(1572097473.688:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-oopslash" pid=1181 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   11.043563] audit: type=1400 audit(1572097473.688:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=1179 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   11.043565] audit: type=1400 audit(1572097473.688:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper" pid=1179 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   11.043793] audit: type=1400 audit(1572097473.688:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/man" pid=1177 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   11.043795] audit: type=1400 audit(1572097473.688:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="man_filter" pid=1177 comm="apparmor_parser"
```

---

I partitioned my drive like so:

- `/dev/sda1` - 500MB - FAT32 - EFI System Partition (`/boot/efi`)
- `/dev/sda2` - 500MB - EXT4  - Boot partition (`/boot`)
- `/dev/sda3` -  - LVM on LUKS

  - `/dev/luks/swap` - 20GB - swap
  - `/dev/luks/ubuntu-19_04` - 35GB - EXT4 - Ubuntu 19.04 root partition (`/`)
  - `/dev/luks/PopOS-19_10` - 30GB - EXT4 - Pop!_OS 19.10 root partition (`/`)
  - `/dev/luks/tmproot` - 25GB - EXT4 - Temporary ubuntu 19.04 root partition (`/`, I'm using this (almost fresh) installation to write this post and try to repair my system)
  - `/dev/luks/data` -  - EXT4 - Data partition (`/disks/main`)

blkid:

```
root@tmp-os:/# blkid
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: UUID="A96B-7B47" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="c0960fdd-bbf3-497f-bbcd-c75d671a1682"
/dev/sda2: UUID="d52d7993-7e37-4ec4-94aa-8f69e97ce836" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="625dd12b-d9c9-4cd0-b09c-8b6b708e998e"
/dev/sda3: UUID="7d295d1c-863f-4ba1-9c84-5e91e3d24b18" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTLABEL="luks" PARTUUID="0fb4ecc8-9857-49ee-95bb-4e756e0834f6"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="myHDD" UUID="c489e309-8b25-49cb-97c3-a5f8b8ba3fe5" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="3b3c5177-01"
/dev/mapper/luks: UUID="0FZHWe-Os0U-JJZ9-bbKP-fvmN-WY7i-x4EU0c" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/mapper/luks-swap: UUID="a2a4712b-b7b3-485f-8346-66c8e38252f9" TYPE="swap"
/dev/mapper/luks-ubuntu--19_04: LABEL="Ubuntu 19.04" UUID="c9ab03a5-a047-4f06-a93f-db38d166b91e" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/luks-data: UUID="86f5d13d-f1e3-4861-84ed-acd4da88d015" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/luks-PopOS--19_10: LABEL="Pop!_OS 19.10" UUID="9fe65b62-0546-4325-a137-b0edcd4b34b7" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/luks-tmproot: UUID="a5121223-8d75-4358-aa3b-8d9ec35bdb1d" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
```

`fdisk -l /dev/sda`:

```
root@tmp-os:/# fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 860 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: B6B1B467-7565-43B4-BA87-638E635B7A10

Device       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048    1026046    1023999  500M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1026048    2050046    1023999  500M EFI System
/dev/sda3  2050048 3907028991 3904978944  1.8T Linux filesystem
```

---

**Ubuntu 19.04** (the non-booting OS) **files**:

`/etc/fstab`:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/luks-ubuntu--19_04 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=d52d7993-7e37-4ec4-94aa-8f69e97ce836 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=A96B-7B47 /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/dev/mapper/luks-swap none            swap    sw              0       0

/dev/mapper/luks-data /disks/main ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
/disks/main/homes/ubuntu-19_04 /home none bind 0 0
```

`/etc/crypttab`:

```
# <target name> <source device> <key file> <options>
luks UUID=7d295d1c-863f-4ba1-9c84-5e91e3d24b18 none luks,discard
```

---

**Custom GRUB menuentries** (`/etc/grub.d/06_custom`):

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 1>&2 "Adding custom menuentries"
exec tail -n +4 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
menuentry 'Pop!_OS 19.10' {
  # I won't tinker with this Pop!_OS menuentry until my main OS can boot again
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 3de8a92b-8615-424b-a071-d858ed106007
  linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/mapper/luks-PopOS--19_10 ro quiet splash acpi_osi=! acpi_osi='Windows 2009' pcie_aspm=off
  initrd /initrd.img
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu 19.04' {
  recordfail=1
  insmod gzio
  insmod part_gpt
  insmod ext2
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root d52d7993-7e37-4ec4-94aa-8f69e97ce836
  linux /vmlinuz-5.0.0-13-generic cryptdevice=UUID=7d295d1c-863f-4ba1-9c84-5e91e3d24b18 root=/dev/mapper/luks-ubuntu--19_04 ro acpi_osi=! acpi_osi='Windows 2009' pcie_aspm=off
  initrd /initrd.img-5.0.0-13-generic
}
menuentry 'Shutdown' {
  echo "System shutting down..."
  halt
}
```

---

Any help is much appreciated!

---

Update 1:

Since I can't seem to mount fat32 filesystems on the broken install I've just copied the `/boot/efi` folder contents to my ext4 drive while on the working install of ubuntu, so I can `mount --bind /disks/main/efi-backup /boot/efi` when dropped to the shell on my broken ubuntu.
This allowes to boot the computer up and I could log in and use my programs, but several devices (i.e. bluetooth,  wifi, ...) were not recognized.
While this is not a solution to the problem, at least I can copy my settings to a working OS.

Comment: Your screenshot says it's actually trying to mount to `/mnt/efi`, not `/boot/efi` - even when you explicitly specify to mount to `/boot/efi`. And GRUB is not to blame here: at the point the problem appears, it's already long gone, its job done. Check the `/etc/fstab` of your failing Ubuntu installation for errors, and anything that might have replaced `/sbin/mount`. You can even temporarily comment out the boot entry for `/boot/efi` for troubleshooting - it only needs to be present and mounted when installing kernel or bootloader updates.

Comment: @simon-l I actually now suffer from the same problem! Same issues as you describe. IO charset isoxxx not found. But also my network devices are not recognized. I tried to run `modprobe` without luck. Nothing work. WHAT IS HAPPENING!?

Comment: @MelroyvandenBerg I've since done a clean reinstall of another distro since I couldn't figure out what went wrong or how to fix it. Sorry to disappoint.

Comment: I think my disk went corrupt as well suddenly. Looks like Linux is/was unable to load all kind of kernel modules. And this IO charset error message is just the tip of the iceberg of the real problem. Still unsure why my OS disk got corrupted, but I will also go for a reinstall.

Comment: Ps. also running `fsck -f <device>` (with the `-f` option) show a lot of strange inode issues, showing indeed that the inode data is corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

**Your Linux modules directory has been removed.**

This happens during system upgrades and things.  You are in the middle of upgrades, when something removes `linux-modules-$(uname -r)` (Ubuntu/Debian package name), and you don't notice until the next time you try to load a module.

Which, for a lot of people, who have a more or less complete set of modules needed to boot on their `initrd` images, is probably when you try to mount your EFI partition.  Maybe it was somewhere else, but you're on this page, so that's probably it.

Solution is to re–install the package you are missing; the package name you want is (again, Debian/Ubuntu–specific):

> `echo linux-modules-$(uname -r)`

If you can't `apt install` that package name, then try googling the package name and see if you can find a link to the old file from `archive.ubuntu.com` or the Debian equivalent.  You'll need to install the `modules` package and the `linux-image` package.

This worked for me.  I avoided rebooting the machine until I could restore the Linux modules for the version it was running, and then run `update-grub` as well as `dpkg --configure -a` to re–configure the various EFI packages (which had failed when they tried to mount the EFI partition).